# long table working in TexNiccenter but not in R Studio GUI

Tags: tables, longtable, texniccenter, rstudio

I'm having a weird error where my code is working just fine in TexNiccenter but unable to compile within the R studio GUI (probably not an R studio problem just R problem). Here's some background: my tables were overflowing and did not fit within the page so I tried to implement the longtable package to fit the tables within the pdf. My friend helped me construct the workable code in TexNiccenter but I can't reproduce it within R studio. Can anyone look at my code and point me in the right direction as to how to get it workable within studio?

Here's my code:

```
%LANDSCAPE MODE FOR TABLE
\usepackage{pdflscape}

%Footnotes become endnotes
%\usepackage{endnotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/endnotes
%\let\footnote\endnote



\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{titling}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\lhead{}
%\chead{}
%\rhead{\thepage}
%\lfoot{}
%\cfoot{}
%\rfoot{}

%\setlength{\droptitle}{2em}   % This is your set screw

\usepackage[margin=0.95in]{geometry}





%Landscape Mode for PDF
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
%============Article Title, Authors================



\usepackage{longtable}
%===================Startup========================
\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}{| p{.40\textwidth} | p{.80\textwidth} |} 
  \hline
 & Belgiumtotal & Germanytotal & Estoniatotal & Irelandtotal & Greecetotal & Spaintotal & Francetotal & Italytotal & Cyprustotal & Latviatotal & Luxembourgtotal & Maltatotal & Netherlandstotal & Austriatotal & Portugaltotal & Sloveniatotal & Slovakiatotal & Finlandtotal \\ 
  \hline
Belgiumtotal & 1.00 & 0.49 & 0.57 & 0.88 & 0.34 & 0.98 & 0.97 & 0.98 & 0.91 & 0.26 & 0.96 & 0.42 & 0.94 & 0.85 & 0.91 & 0.96 & 0.88 & 0.98 \\ 
  Germanytotal & 0.49 & 1.00 & 0.93 & 0.73 & 0.71 & 0.53 & 0.60 & 0.63 & 0.32 & 0.88 & 0.68 & -0.05 & 0.69 & 0.86 & 0.72 & 0.52 & 0.82 & 0.51 \\ 
  Estoniatotal & 0.57 & 0.93 & 1.00 & 0.83 & 0.75 & 0.61 & 0.64 & 0.69 & 0.41 & 0.93 & 0.75 & 0.15 & 0.70 & 0.88 & 0.73 & 0.58 & 0.80 & 0.56 \\ 
  Irelandtotal & 0.88 & 0.73 & 0.83 & 1.00 & 0.66 & 0.93 & 0.91 & 0.94 & 0.72 & 0.65 & 0.94 & 0.20 & 0.95 & 0.94 & 0.94 & 0.92 & 0.92 & 0.85 \\ 
  Greecetotal & 0.34 & 0.71 & 0.75 & 0.66 & 1.00 & 0.44 & 0.39 & 0.43 & 0.18 & 0.75 & 0.49 & -0.23 & 0.54 & 0.56 & 0.49 & 0.45 & 0.53 & 0.28 \\ 
  Spaintotal & 0.98 & 0.53 & 0.61 & 0.93 & 0.44 & 1.00 & 0.98 & 0.97 & 0.90 & 0.34 & 0.94 & 0.27 & 0.96 & 0.87 & 0.94 & 1.00 & 0.90 & 0.97 \\ 
  Francetotal & 0.97 & 0.60 & 0.64 & 0.91 & 0.39 & 0.98 & 1.00 & 0.98 & 0.91 & 0.37 & 0.95 & 0.28 & 0.97 & 0.91 & 0.95 & 0.98 & 0.94 & 0.99 \\ 
  Italytotal & 0.98 & 0.63 & 0.69 & 0.94 & 0.43 & 0.97 & 0.98 & 1.00 & 0.86 & 0.42 & 0.99 & 0.39 & 0.96 & 0.93 & 0.94 & 0.95 & 0.94 & 0.97 \\ 
  Cyprustotal & 0.91 & 0.32 & 0.41 & 0.72 & 0.18 & 0.90 & 0.91 & 0.86 & 1.00 & 0.09 & 0.84 & 0.42 & 0.80 & 0.72 & 0.79 & 0.89 & 0.78 & 0.95 \\ 
  Latviatotal & 0.26 & 0.88 & 0.93 & 0.65 & 0.75 & 0.34 & 0.37 & 0.42 & 0.09 & 1.00 & 0.47 & -0.10 & 0.47 & 0.69 & 0.52 & 0.33 & 0.59 & 0.26 \\ 
  Luxembourgtotal & 0.96 & 0.68 & 0.75 & 0.94 & 0.49 & 0.94 & 0.95 & 0.99 & 0.84 & 0.47 & 1.00 & 0.43 & 0.94 & 0.93 & 0.92 & 0.92 & 0.93 & 0.94 \\ 
  Maltatotal & 0.42 & -0.05 & 0.15 & 0.20 & -0.23 & 0.27 & 0.28 & 0.39 & 0.42 & -0.10 & 0.43 & 1.00 & 0.13 & 0.21 & 0.13 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 0.38 \\ 
  Netherlandstotal & 0.94 & 0.69 & 0.70 & 0.95 & 0.54 & 0.96 & 0.97 & 0.96 & 0.80 & 0.47 & 0.94 & 0.13 & 1.00 & 0.93 & 0.97 & 0.97 & 0.96 & 0.93 \\ 
  Austriatotal & 0.85 & 0.86 & 0.88 & 0.94 & 0.56 & 0.87 & 0.91 & 0.93 & 0.72 & 0.69 & 0.93 & 0.21 & 0.93 & 1.00 & 0.94 & 0.85 & 0.98 & 0.86 \\ 
  Portugaltotal & 0.91 & 0.72 & 0.73 & 0.94 & 0.49 & 0.94 & 0.95 & 0.94 & 0.79 & 0.52 & 0.92 & 0.13 & 0.97 & 0.94 & 1.00 & 0.94 & 0.97 & 0.92 \\ 
  Sloveniatotal & 0.96 & 0.52 & 0.58 & 0.92 & 0.45 & 1.00 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.89 & 0.33 & 0.92 & 0.18 & 0.97 & 0.85 & 0.94 & 1.00 & 0.90 & 0.96 \\ 
  Slovakiatotal & 0.88 & 0.82 & 0.80 & 0.92 & 0.53 & 0.90 & 0.94 & 0.94 & 0.78 & 0.59 & 0.93 & 0.15 & 0.96 & 0.98 & 0.97 & 0.90 & 1.00 & 0.90 \\ 
  Finlandtotal & 0.98 & 0.51 & 0.56 & 0.85 & 0.28 & 0.97 & 0.99 & 0.97 & 0.95 & 0.26 & 0.94 & 0.38 & 0.93 & 0.86 & 0.92 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 1.00 \\ 
   \hline
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
Table \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} shows my first longtable.

%===================End Document===================
\end{document}
```

^This is working fine within TexNiccenter but when I try in R studio I am getting the `Option Clash for geometry` error as well as the `extra alignment tab` error

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: You have two column specifiers `{p.....|p....}` but many columns, that's why you get `extra &` errors. That's one. And try loading geometry package without the `[margin...]` option. Are you sure TC doesn't give errors?

Comment: as percuse says the tex file is in error so the error is unrelated to which editor (texniccenter or rstudio) you use. The example as posted is also missing  `\documentclass`

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have tried correcting the code per your suggestions and am getting a slew of other errors. This is what I have done given both of your comments:

Answer (score 1):

Your table had several errors so would generate errors with any editor.  I also increased row height to keep text away from the rules, and reduced the font size and added negative spacing to allow the table to steal space from the margins, finally I rotated the headings, so the table just about fits on the width of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%LANDSCAPE MODE FOR TABLE
\usepackage{graphicx,pdflscape}

%Footnotes become endnotes
%\usepackage{endnotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/endnotes
%\let\footnote\endnote



\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{titling}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\lhead{}
%\chead{}
%\rhead{\thepage}
%\lfoot{}
%\cfoot{}
%\rfoot{}

%\setlength{\droptitle}{2em}   % This is your set screw

\usepackage[margin=0.95in]{geometry}


%Landscape Mode for PDF
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
%============Article Title, Authors================

\newcommand\Hd[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1 }}

\usepackage{array,longtable}
%===================Startup========================
\begin{document} 
\footnotesize
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\LTleft{-50pt}
\setlength\LTright{-50pt plus 1fill}
\begin{longtable}{|*{19}{r|}|} 
  \hline
 & \Hd{Belgium} & \Hd{Germany} & \Hd{Estonia} & \Hd{Ireland} & \Hd{Greece} & \Hd{Spain} & \Hd{France} & \Hd{Italy} & \Hd{Cyprus} & \Hd{Latvia} & \Hd{Luxembourg} & \Hd{Malta} & \Hd{Netherlands} & \Hd{Austria} & \Hd{Portugal} & \Hd{Slovenia} & \Hd{Slovakia} & \Hd{Finland} \\ 
  \hline
Belgium & 1.00 & 0.49 & 0.57 & 0.88 & 0.34 & 0.98 & 0.97 & 0.98 & 0.91 & 0.26 & 0.96 & 0.42 & 0.94 & 0.85 & 0.91 & 0.96 & 0.88 & 0.98 \\ 
  Germany & 0.49 & 1.00 & 0.93 & 0.73 & 0.71 & 0.53 & 0.60 & 0.63 & 0.32 & 0.88 & 0.68 & -0.05 & 0.69 & 0.86 & 0.72 & 0.52 & 0.82 & 0.51 \\ 
  Estonia & 0.57 & 0.93 & 1.00 & 0.83 & 0.75 & 0.61 & 0.64 & 0.69 & 0.41 & 0.93 & 0.75 & 0.15 & 0.70 & 0.88 & 0.73 & 0.58 & 0.80 & 0.56 \\ 
  Ireland & 0.88 & 0.73 & 0.83 & 1.00 & 0.66 & 0.93 & 0.91 & 0.94 & 0.72 & 0.65 & 0.94 & 0.20 & 0.95 & 0.94 & 0.94 & 0.92 & 0.92 & 0.85 \\ 
  Greece & 0.34 & 0.71 & 0.75 & 0.66 & 1.00 & 0.44 & 0.39 & 0.43 & 0.18 & 0.75 & 0.49 & -0.23 & 0.54 & 0.56 & 0.49 & 0.45 & 0.53 & 0.28 \\ 
  Spain & 0.98 & 0.53 & 0.61 & 0.93 & 0.44 & 1.00 & 0.98 & 0.97 & 0.90 & 0.34 & 0.94 & 0.27 & 0.96 & 0.87 & 0.94 & 1.00 & 0.90 & 0.97 \\ 
  France & 0.97 & 0.60 & 0.64 & 0.91 & 0.39 & 0.98 & 1.00 & 0.98 & 0.91 & 0.37 & 0.95 & 0.28 & 0.97 & 0.91 & 0.95 & 0.98 & 0.94 & 0.99 \\ 
  Italy & 0.98 & 0.63 & 0.69 & 0.94 & 0.43 & 0.97 & 0.98 & 1.00 & 0.86 & 0.42 & 0.99 & 0.39 & 0.96 & 0.93 & 0.94 & 0.95 & 0.94 & 0.97 \\ 
  Cyprus & 0.91 & 0.32 & 0.41 & 0.72 & 0.18 & 0.90 & 0.91 & 0.86 & 1.00 & 0.09 & 0.84 & 0.42 & 0.80 & 0.72 & 0.79 & 0.89 & 0.78 & 0.95 \\ 
  Latvia & 0.26 & 0.88 & 0.93 & 0.65 & 0.75 & 0.34 & 0.37 & 0.42 & 0.09 & 1.00 & 0.47 & -0.10 & 0.47 & 0.69 & 0.52 & 0.33 & 0.59 & 0.26 \\ 
  Luxembourg & 0.96 & 0.68 & 0.75 & 0.94 & 0.49 & 0.94 & 0.95 & 0.99 & 0.84 & 0.47 & 1.00 & 0.43 & 0.94 & 0.93 & 0.92 & 0.92 & 0.93 & 0.94 \\ 
  Malta & 0.42 & -0.05 & 0.15 & 0.20 & -0.23 & 0.27 & 0.28 & 0.39 & 0.42 & -0.10 & 0.43 & 1.00 & 0.13 & 0.21 & 0.13 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 0.38 \\ 
  Netherlands & 0.94 & 0.69 & 0.70 & 0.95 & 0.54 & 0.96 & 0.97 & 0.96 & 0.80 & 0.47 & 0.94 & 0.13 & 1.00 & 0.93 & 0.97 & 0.97 & 0.96 & 0.93 \\ 
  Austria & 0.85 & 0.86 & 0.88 & 0.94 & 0.56 & 0.87 & 0.91 & 0.93 & 0.72 & 0.69 & 0.93 & 0.21 & 0.93 & 1.00 & 0.94 & 0.85 & 0.98 & 0.86 \\ 
  Portugal & 0.91 & 0.72 & 0.73 & 0.94 & 0.49 & 0.94 & 0.95 & 0.94 & 0.79 & 0.52 & 0.92 & 0.13 & 0.97 & 0.94 & 1.00 & 0.94 & 0.97 & 0.92 \\ 
  Slovenia & 0.96 & 0.52 & 0.58 & 0.92 & 0.45 & 1.00 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.89 & 0.33 & 0.92 & 0.18 & 0.97 & 0.85 & 0.94 & 1.00 & 0.90 & 0.96 \\ 
  Slovakia & 0.88 & 0.82 & 0.80 & 0.92 & 0.53 & 0.90 & 0.94 & 0.94 & 0.78 & 0.59 & 0.93 & 0.15 & 0.96 & 0.98 & 0.97 & 0.90 & 1.00 & 0.90 \\ 
  Finland & 0.98 & 0.51 & 0.56 & 0.85 & 0.28 & 0.97 & 0.99 & 0.97 & 0.95 & 0.26 & 0.94 & 0.38 & 0.93 & 0.86 & 0.92 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 1.00 \\ 
   \hline
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
Table \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} shows my first longtable.

%===================End Document===================
\end{document}
```